# How to change the combo box selected value on button click in power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am customizing the SharePoint list form using PowerApps. I have a requirement to change the selected value of the combo box control on the click event of another button.

Actually I tried multiple ways as below to change the selected value in combo box from On click of button. but no success.

Tried ways are as below:

```
[{Value:"option1"}]

["option1"]
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Set the following formula to **OnSelect** property of button:

```
Set(defaultComboValue, LookUp(Choices('SP List'.ChoiceColumnName), Value="option1"))
```

Set the following formula to **DefaultSelectedItems** of combo box:

```
If(IsBlankOrError(defaultComboValue), Parent.Default, defaultComboValue)
```

**References**:

1. [Change the value of a dropdown by clicking a button](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Change-the-value-of-a-dropdown-by-clicking-a-button/td-p/385822)
2. [How To set the selected value of a combo box to one of the choices using PowerApps](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-To-set-the-selected-value-of-a-combo-box-to-one-of-the/td-p/130312)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Actually I am already following the second link you have mentioned.
The approach it mentions it actually changes the combo box selected value, which works fine. Post updating on button click if I try to save the form means I am doing SubmitForm(Form1), it is throwing error as the mentioned combo box contains invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I'm deriving my answer from [the answer given by Ganesh Sanap](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/293412/10239) - [his second link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-To-set-the-selected-value-of-a-combo-box-to-one-of-the/td-p/130312) had what I needed.

My goal was to use a vertical gallery to select an item in a *different* list than the combo box's data source. The ID of the item selected in the gallery would then be used to select the item in the combo box. **It's important to note that these items were related through a list lookup in SharePoint.** This allowed me to display additional information in the gallery and then hide the combo box from the user.

**Basic Elements Involved:**

- Vertical gallery (`selected_kit_gallery`)

  - This is based on my `'Kit Status'` list
- Combo box (name doesn't matter)
- Variable to hold gallery selection (`kitvar`)
- Gallery settings to assign the selected item to the variable (`OnSelect`)
- Combo box settings to select the item that is stored in the variable from the gallery (`DefaultSelectedItems`)

  - This is based on my `'Kit Requests'` lists

**Overview**

1. Build your canvas form - the gallery in this example is called `selected_kit_gallery`
2. Select the "Tree View" (3 stacked squares) in the left hand pane and select "App"
   [image: Tree View for App]
3. Find the `OnStart` property under "Advanced" in the right hand pane to create a variable that will store the selected item from the gallery.

   - You have to point the variable at the gallery when it's created in order for it to assume the correct object type.

     - Don't worry about the rest of my variables, just `kitvar` :)
   - **Example:** `Set(kitvar,selected_kit_gallery.Selected)`
   - [image: Set variable in OnStart using the selected item from the gallery]
4. Now, find your gallery and click on the "Select" arrow

   - [image: Select Arrow for Gallery]
   - Next find the `OnSelect` property and make it change the variable to the gallery's selected item
   - **Example:** `Set(kitvar,selected_kit_gallery.Selected)`
   - [image: Gallery OnSelect action]
5. Now find your combo box data card and click on the combo box itself:

   - [image: Combo Box Selected Directly]
   - Find the combo box's `DefaultSelectedItems` under the "Advanced" tab in the right hand pane

     - Set this so that it will reference the `kitvar` variable and allow the combo box to follow whatever is selected in the gallery
   - **Example:** `Filter(Choices('Kit Requests'.assigned_kit),Id=kitvar.ID)`
   - [image: Combo Box DefaultSelectedItems]

I've actually tweaked a lot more in the gallery so that it's obvious to the user once a kit has been selected. This took me a lot longer to figure out than it should have! Hope it helps someone else.